# Return only the item with 10th total Sale

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a query that ONLY returns the item which has the 10th totalSale value. I know that I can use TOP to get the first 10items, but I want it to only show the 10th item. Here is the query that I have written:

```
SELECT TOP 10 D_I.ID, SUM(F_S.Sale) AS TOTALSALE 
FROM Dim_ItemsD_I JOIN FCT_Sales F_S ON D_I.ID = F_S.ID
GROUP BY D_I.ID
```

Please help! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery. Order the first 10 items in descending order then select the first item:

```
 select top 1 ITEM, TOTALSALE 
 from
    (select top 10 D_I.ITEM, SUM(F_S.Sale) as TOTALSALE 
     from Dim_Items D_I
     join FCT_Sales F_S on D_I.ID = F_S.Item_ID
     group by D_I.Item 
     order by TOTALSALE DESC) T
```

Check here for a simplified example: http://rextester.com/live/SAOQ22288

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: It works perfectly @TienNguyen, see my small example http://rextester.com/JIXUN12802

Comment: I don't know why I got a down vote. Anyways, I added an example link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.TOTALSALE
FROM
(
    SELECT
        D_I.ID,
        SUM(F_S.Sale) AS TOTALSALE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(F_S.Sale) DESC) rn
    FROM Dim_Items D_I
    JOIN FCT_Sales F_S
        ON D_I.ID = F_S.ID
    GROUP BY D_I.ID
) t
WHERE t.rn = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D_I.ID, SUM(F_S.Sale) AS TOTALSALE      
FROM Dim_ItemsD_I 
JOIN FCT_Sales F_S 
ON D_I.ID = F_S.ID 
GROUP BY D_I.ID 
Offset 9 rows fetch next 1 rows only
Order by TotalSale
```

Offset will skip the first 9 rows, next 1 row will be selected. Do order by asc or desc , based on your requirement.